# How to use const auto with STLport library

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, stlport

I've tried to compile elementary example:

```
#include <vector>
int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> testV;
    for (const auto& test : testV) 
    {   }
    return 0;
}
```

And I've received error:
    `test.cpp: In function 'int main()':`
`test.cpp:5:29: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope`
`test.cpp:5:29: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope`
`test.cpp:5:29: error: unable to deduce 'const auto&' from '<expression error>'`

Does STLport support `const auto` ?

**EDIT: I'm using `GCC 4.6`**
With 4.7 and more everything is ok.

Comment: it depends on your compiler, which version and what compiler are you using?

Comment: `auto` is a feature of the compiler. Looks like the STLport library doesn't support non-member begin and end. Actually that may be a lie, try including `<iterator>`.

Comment: could you try `#include<iterator>`? it should be included by `<vector> ` already but you never know...

Comment: Actually, I remember now it looks for the *member* versions first. Then the non-member ones (6.5.4). So it should work.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks, I will try latest STLport version

Comment: @TemplateRex Please check section 6.5.4 of The Standard. This seems to be a very common misconception, but the member versions **are** looked for first. Then non-member versions via ADL (no normal lookup), with `std::` considered an associated namespace. ([pasted here](http://pastebin.com/iNz9mRjm), but bad formatting)

Comment: @BoBTFish darn, you are right, [this simple test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c4ab5abcad5477e4869467fdd34d44b5-c96156d6cc95286981b0e9deef2eefae) confirms it

Comment: @TemplateRex With gcc 4.7 and more everything is ok, but for 4.6 test failed.

Comment: @Pepelac it is a mysterious bug, see my answer to possible clues and solution.

Comment: @BoBTFish The misconception is at least partly because older versions of C++0x before the official C++11 actually only looked for non-members (but the template `std::begin` and `std::end` just defer to the member functions anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc 4.6 came out in the spring of 2011, was not without bugs in most C++11 features. Moroever, around the same time the rules for ADL lookup in range-for were also modified (note that this was prior to the official ratification of the C++11 Standard in the summer of 2011). See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5200101/819272) for more details. It's probably not worth debugging this and the recommended course of action is to upgrade to a recent version of gcc (4.7 or preferably 4.8).