# Range-Based For Loop and ADL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, argument-dependent-lookup

This is an extension to this question from 2011:
[Range-based for loops and ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5200101/941915)

Using Visual Studio 2015, I'm not able to make a range-based for loop for a custom container using Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL).

I have made a very simple test case below with a custom container:

```
#include <vector>

namespace Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    class Container
    {
    public:

        std::vector<T> values;
    };
}

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin(Foo::Container<T>& foo)
{
    return foo.values.begin();
}

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator end(Foo::Container<T>& foo)
{
    return foo.values.end();
}
```

Using this container and ADL, the following test compiles perfectly fine:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo::Container<int> values;

    for (auto it = begin(values); it != end(values); ++it)
    {
        ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As it should. I'm not sure if ADL is even being utilized here, but regardless, it makes sense. From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203382.aspx), we have:

> Keep in mind these facts about range-based for:
>
> - Automatically recognizes arrays.
> - Recognizes containers that have .begin() and .end().
> - Uses argument-dependent lookup begin() and end() for anything else.

From what I understand of ADL, and the documentation above, the following should also compile:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo::Container<int> values;

    for (auto value : values)
    {
        ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't. Instead, I get the following errors:

```
error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'Foo::Container<int>'
error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'Foo::Container<int>'
```

So what's going on here? Is my interpretation of ADL incorrect, or is this a bug with MSVC 14.0 Compiler?

Comment: IINM `begin()` and `end()` should be in `Foo`.

Comment: This is not dependent on ADL since `begin` and `end` are not in the namespace `Foo`, but it seems to work fine in gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12047609140d05a9 . If you change `begin` and `end` to take a `const` ref instead, does it work on MSVC?

Comment: @rici, No, it doesn't. It makes me wonder why it works in GCC though if Pavlo's answer is right. Which compiler is the correct one?! :)

Comment: @Zeenobit In C++11, both are kind of correct since the standard had a defect, and in C++14, your code must be rejected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to place both `begin` and `end` into `Foo` namespace for ADL to work. This is because ADL will look into namespaces of corresponding arguments to search definitions of `begin` and `end`.

```
namespace Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    class Container
    {
    public:

        std::vector<T> values;
    };

    template <typename T>
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin(Foo::Container<T>& foo)
    {
        return foo.values.begin();
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator end(Foo::Container<T>& foo)
    {
        return foo.values.end();
    }
}
```

**UPD:** The reason why `begin` and `end` from global namespace are not considered is because of the updated standard saying that `begin` and `end` are looked up in the associated namespaces but ordinary unqualiﬁed lookup is not performed. This is a consequence of bug fix in the standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1442).

Comment: It should work fine with `begin` and `end` defined in the global namespace, too. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @rici this is because ordinary unqualified lookup (lookup in global namespace) is not performed according to updated standard:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1442

Comment: @PavloMur Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: pavlo: Interesting, thanks. I'd completely missed that change.