# Range-based for loop: why is ordinary lookup not performed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, name-lookup, range-based-loop

In range-based `for` when *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(range)` and `end(range)`, the names `begin` and `end` are not looked up using ordinary lookup. Just ADL is performed. See C++23 [[stmt.ranged]#1.3.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/stmt.ranged#1.3.3).

Why is ordinary lookup skipped?

Comment: It's not skipped, if "ordinary" lookup fails then ADL is used

Comment: @TerenceSimpson no, thats not correct

Comment: Going off the conditions listed, it's the last option tried

Comment: @TerenceSimpson the first bullet is for arrays, the second for members `begin` and `end` and there is no bullet for ordinary name lookup before ADL gets its turn in the last bullet, the note explictily states that it is not performed

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681697/range-based-for-loop-and-adl and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1442

Comment: Except to enforce the use of namespaces, it's indeed strange that ordinary unqualified lookup is skipped.

Comment: You can write an example code to test it.

Comment: From what I can tell [ranged for was first introduced with the expectation that concepts would be used to enforce the correct behavior](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2778.htm).  Since that got scrapped for C++11 they had to [rework the proposal for ranged for](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html) and there they chose ADL to limit the selection of the range functions.

Comment: My belief is this was done to avoid cases where if you had `begin` or `end` that takes the container type but does not return an iterator then those functions would be avoided.

Comment: @NathanOliver: How does skipping ordinary lookup avoid that? Functions returning anything can appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Dr.Gut they can, but limiting the scope to ADL means you are less likely to pull in an unrelated function.

Answer (score 4):

Because for types without member `begin`/`end` the following would be silly:

```
void accum(std::valarray<int> &v,int begin=0) {
  for(auto &x : v) x=begin+=x;  // error: cannot call expression of type 'int'
}
```